'pyinstall --onefile' option but using 'flet build windows' instead?
I would like to use pyinstaller.exe --onefile, but using the command line flet build windows to compact all the .\\build directory generated by flet build windows into a single .exe file. How can I do this over the commandline?
I just want to deploy a python/flet application into windows .exe single file.

I read Flet's documentation and there is no option to compile Python code to one .exe file using Flet, but pyinstaller and command pyinstaller.exe --onefile work pretty fine with Flet framework.
